# Generating link preview in RecyclerView, possible options?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to populate a RecyclerView with items that contains preview of a link from the web! What are my choices available in Android?

**PS:** I referred this [library](https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview), but helpless to use inside a `RecyclerView` .

Any other methods?

Comment: Post the code on how you're using the RecyclerView and it's Adapter please.

Comment: Would it help? It's the good old way of defining a recyclerview, Loading values as JSON and converting them using GSON, and storing that as list, and its assigned to the RecyclerView,  and the adapter to be obvious , is minimal, that contains necessary materials, onCreateViewHolder, on attached and onBind,  can post if necessary, all I am looking for is options, I can implement, thanks :)